# Models missing error while migrating Django project from dev to production

Tags: python, django

I have setup a Django project on my laptop and build my first app. I have setup all the necessary software on a second server and I want to migrate my project to that one.

After uploading my files, I have tried a couple of things, but I still get errors like:

```
ImportError at /
No module named myapp.models
Request Method: GET
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named myapp.models
Exception Location: /var/www/wsgi/myproject/myapp/admin.py in <module>, line 2
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.5
```

The problematic line on **admin.py** looks like:

```
from myapp.models import (...)
```

and file **models.py** in this app has the necessary stuff, so I guess it **can't resolve the app namespace** or something?

Comment: Do you also import admin into models? If so you have a circular dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `PYTHONPATH` doesn't include `/var/www/wsgi/myproject`. Can you show your WSGI config file?

Comment: try adding sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/wsgi/myproject/') so myapp becomes a findable path

Answer (score 1):

You may need to move/create an `__init__.py` file in your app directory.